# Why inline assembly and optimization generates a problem with rbit

Tags: c++, c, assembly, arm, inline-assembly

The following code:

```c
#include <cstdint>

uint8_t res{};

//__attribute__ ((noinline))
static uint8_t reverse_bits() {
    uint32_t word = 10;
    asm("rbit %1,%0" : "=r"(word) : "r"(word));
    word >>= 24;
    return word;
}

void calc() {
    res ^= reverse_bits();
}

int main() {
    calc();
    return res;
}
```

Produces this assembler code when compiled with *Os* on GCC ARM 9.3:

```
│0x8002a80 <main()>              ldr    r2, [pc, #16]   ; (0x8002a94 <main()+20>)                                                                                                        │
│0x8002a82 <main()+2>            movs   r0, #10                                                                                                                                          │
│0x8002a84 <main()+4>            rbit   r0, r3                                                                                                                                           │
│0x8002a88 <main()+8>            ldrb   r0, [r2, #0]                                                                                                                                     │
│0x8002a8a <main()+10>           eor.w  r0, r0, r3, lsr #24                                                                                                                              │
│0x8002a8e <main()+14>           strb   r0, [r2, #0]                                                                                                                                     │
│0x8002a90 <main()+16>           bx     lr                                                                                                                                               │
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/96zjhr4hP

The code produces a wrong runtime result. 0 instead of 80. If I force no inline, the output is correct. The assembly generated is:

```
│0x80003a2 <reverse_bits()>              movs   r0, #10                                                                                                                                  │
│0x80003a4 <reverse_bits()+2>            rbit   r0, r0                                                                                                                                   │
│0x80003a8 <reverse_bits()+6>            lsrs   r0, r0, #24                                                                                                                              │
│0x80003aa <reverse_bits()+8>            bx     lr        

│0x8002a90 <main()>              push   {r3, lr}                                                                                                                                         │
│0x8002a92 <main()+2>            bl     0x80003a2 <reverse_bits()>                                                                                                                       │
│0x8002a96 <main()+6>            ldr    r3, [pc, #12]   ; (0x8002aa4 <main()+20>)                                                                                                        │
│0x8002a98 <main()+8>            ldrb   r2, [r3, #0]                                                                                                                                     │
│0x8002a9a <main()+10>           eors   r0, r2                                                                                                                                           │
│0x8002a9c <main()+12>           uxtb   r0, r0                                                                                                                                           │
│0x8002a9e <main()+14>           strb   r0, [r3, #0]                                                                                                                                     │
│0x8002aa0 <main()+16>           pop    {r3, pc}                                                                                                                                         │
│0x8002aa2 <main()+18>           nop                                                                                                                                                     │
│0x8002aa4 <main()+20>           lsrs   r4, r7, #16                                                                                                                                      │
│0x8002aa6 <main()+22>           movs   r0, #32
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/G4Ex7rsbx

What is wrong with the inline assembly?

P.S. RBit is really handy on some places, because it reverse the bits in a single instruction.

Comment: ARM has destination, src operand order.  Flip the operands around.

Comment: This seems to be the issue!
The assembler code is compiled from C++.

Comment: Could it be a compiler bug?

Comment: No, that's the way it's supposed to be. In one case it just happened to work, because of the way it set things up. Your code is incorrect, so it just got lucky to work in one of the cases.

Comment: Can you please explain to me, what is incorrect on my C++ code?

Comment: @Viatorus You inline assembly statements has the operands in the wrong order.  Change `rbit %1,%0` to `rbit %0, %1` and it should work just fine.  Refer to the ARM architecture reference manual for details.

Comment: Oh, you are absolut right. I first thought I should change the compiled assembler code. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you're using clang, use `__builtin_bitreverse32` instead of inline asm (https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#builtin-bitreverse).  Or with Keil, `__rbit`.  Unfortunately GCC is still missing an intrinsic for it (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50481).